# Unit Testing Lambda Expressions

Tags: unit-testing, lambda, java-8

I have a method that is shown as below and this in turn call multiple private methods, that I won't be posting here.

```
@Bean
    public CommandLineRunner registerStartersAndReaders(final Vertx vertx, final SpringVerticleFactory springVerticleFactory,
                                                        final SpringUtil springUtil, final GslConfig gslConfig) {
        return args -> {
            // Scan all the beans annotated with the @ElasticsearchBatchDataListener annotation.
            List<Pair<Object, Method>> listenerMethods = springUtil.getListenerMethods();

            // Deploy the starters per listener.
            deployVerticle(listenerMethods, jsonConfig -> deployStarterVerticle(vertx, springVerticleFactory, jsonConfig), config);

            // Deploy the reader verticles.
            deployVerticle(listenerMethods, jsonConfig -> deployReaderVerticle(vertx, springVerticleFactory, jsonConfig), config);
            setupTriggers(vertx, listenerMethods, config);
        };
    }
```

Then I have a test method for it :

```
@Test
    public void registerStartersAndReadersTest() {
        when(springUtil.getListenerMethods()).thenReturn(value);
        CommandLineRunner runner = config.registerStartersAndReaders(vertx, springVerticleFactory, springUtil, config);
        assertNotNull(runner);
    }
```

Here, all the parameters passed into the method call are mocks. The problem is, when I run this test, it passes but it returns the value without getting into the private methods as it just returns 'args'.

Can someone please guide me, as to how I can make my test cover all the possible code. I am not supposed to change my code for the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got confused with the lamba expression, and believe me it is very confusing in the beginning. But once you are fluent with it, it will be a breeze.

So here you got the instance of `CommandLineRunner` from method `registerStartersAndReaders` call, and your assertNotNull `PASS` as you have the not null instance, but until you call the `run` method of `FunctionalInterface` nothing will be executed. 
Add `runner.run(args)` to execute the method(s) in your test case.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I really got confused as this is the first time I am working with these expressions. But adding the runner.run(args) code, has solved multiple issues. :)

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [What should I do when someone answers my question?] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @J.Akansha - As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time. Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well.